# GCP Apache Beam Dataflow JDBC IO Connection Error

Tags: java, oracle, apache-beam, ojdbc, apache-beam-io

## Problem

When trying to deploy an Apache Beam Pipeline on Google Cloud Platform Dataflow service which connects to a **Oracle 11gR2 (11.2.0.4) database** to retrieve rows, I received the following error when using the [Apache Beam JdbCIO Transform](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.html):

> Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01882: timezone region not found )

Answer (score 1):

## To solve the problem, I updated the pom.xml

```
<!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc6 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Any idea why that helped? The error about the timezone does not hint at an ojdbc library. Did you add this artifact or use more recent version?

Comment: when using ojdbc8 drivers, I had to update the `defaultConnectionProperties.properties` and add the line `oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false`